# How to open this software downloaded from GitHub?

Tags: github

I have downloaded [ArmorPaint from GitHub](https://github.com/armory3d/armorpaint), and, considering I am new to programming, how am I supposed to launch this software?

As you can see in the picture below, there is no `exe` file visible.

[image: repository content]

Where can I find the executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the [executable download](https://armorpaint.org/download.html) is not free, you have to follow the instruction of the [`README`](https://github.com/armory3d/armorpaint/blob/6f8e11285faf5d89db750435856d3e7fe8b5f941/README.md) and compile it yourself.

That means having the right compiler and dependencies installed first.

- Windows: [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)
- Linux: [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) + [deps](https://github.com/Kode/Kha/wiki/Linux)
- MacOS / iOS: [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/)
- Android: [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)
- nodejs
- Git